# Comment appelle-t-on ces trucmuches sur les bretelles permettant d'en ajuster la longueur ?

Tags: terminologie, habillement

[image]
<sub>Adapté de l'[original](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Bib-brace.jpg) (User *Stuz* sur [en.wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/), GFDL/cc by-sa)</sub>

- Sur une [*salopette*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/salopette) ([Wiki.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salopette)), par exemple, comment appelle-t-on ces
  trucmuches sur les bretelles permettant d'en ajuster la longueur ?
- À défaut ou au surplus d'un terme plus précis, quel terme générique emploie-t-on usuellement pour désigner cet élément ou sa fonction sur un vêtement ou un accessoire ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le réglage de la longueur des bretelles peut se faire au moyen de [boucles à coulisse](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22boucle%20%C3%A0%20coulisse%22&lr=&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6oInwsKfMAhUDfRoKHSTbCQUQ_AUIBygB&biw=1855&bih=927)*.

Ceux qui fabriquent eux-mêmes leurs vêtements trouvent cet accessoire dans les magasins qui vendent des fournitures de mercerie.

*Appelées aussi  « [boucles coulissantes](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22boucle%20%C3%A0%20coulisse%22&lr=&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6oInwsKfMAhUDfRoKHSTbCQUQ_AUIBygB&biw=1855&bih=927#tbm=isch&q=%22boucle%20coulissante%22) »

Comment: @L'aditdabenlà On pourrait  aussi « régler  » la longueur de bretelles, je ne vois rien d'autre.

Comment: @L'aditdabenlà  On peut employer le mot « fourniture » [TLF B1](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/fourniture).  Mais on n'emploierait pas le mot tout seul, on dit « fournitures de mercerie », « fournitures de bureau » etc. Plutôt employé au pluriel (comme un générique) mais ça ne me choque pas de dire « la fourniture de mercerie qu'est la boucle à coulisse sert au réglage (à l'ajustement) des bretelles » même si ça fait plutôt définition que langage spontané.