# « La boucle du manteau de Jean s'est déchirée » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, compléments, habillement

Certains manteaux disposent d'une petite *boucle* (une [autre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18816) ?) dans laquelle on peut insérer le crochet d'une patère pour les y faire tenir... :

[image]
<sup><sup>Image d'une partie d'un manteau avec sa boucle.</sup></sup>

---

- A-t-on un terme plus précis que « boucle » pour la désigner ?
- Sinon quel complément (complément du nom, adjectif,
  locution prépositionnelle, verbale etc.) utilise-t-on le plus *couramment/fréquemment* pour préciser ce dont il s'agit dans une phrase comme celle-ci :

  > La boucle du manteau de Jean s'est déchirée. [imprécis]

Comment: Just to note an English connection w/the use of “boucle” in French (& in passing, a questionable alternative to it), the “Gants” discussed [HERE](http://le-vestiaire-de-jim.com/2015/09/23/focus-on-gant-rugger-aw15/) were de rigueur in '67, even for those of us just turning 13 that year. Their curious exterior hanging **loops**, aka “locker **loops**” [patte d’accrochage?/«boucle de vestiaire»?] (we innocently called them “fruit **loops**," as in ”Toucan Sam’s favorite cereal) were “snatched” by girlfriends, often along w/torn strips of fabric & always along w/soon-to-be broken teenage hearts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le terme reçu en France pour cet objet qui sert à suspendre un vêtement est : « bride »,  ou de façon plus technique « **bride de suspension** ».

On peut acheter une bride, [chaînette en métal](http://www.a-et-a.com/tous_les_produits_fr/chainette-de-suspension-pour-manteau-ou-veste.html) ou [objet fait  d'un autre matériau](http://www.a-et-a.com/tous_les_produits_fr/bride-de-suspension-pour-manteau-ou-veste.html) que l'on coudra soi-même à un vêtement qui n'en possède pas à l'origine. On peut aussi la faire soi-même : comment faire une bride et la fixer soi-même  sur le vêtement [sur un site de couture](http://www.coupecouture.fr/2014/02/bride_en_tissu.html).

En France la plupart des [torchons](http://www.prixi.com/productInfo/00W075090/159/2-torchons-de-cuisine-anis-a-pois-45-x-70-cm/) de cuisine sont vendus avec des brides de suspension.

On trouve rarement (au contraire de la Grande-Bretagne) des brides de suspension aux jupes et pantalons achetés en-prêt-à porter en France. Au Canada la [jupe de cérémonie de la Gendarmerie Royale](https://buyandsell.gc.ca/cds/public/2013/10/22/1e0a2fa6dcbcc4b93beac10a876b8647/165_skirt_blue_formal_length_french.pdf) doit être pourvue de

> brides de suspension de style ruban,offertes sur le marché, de couleur noire ou bleu marine foncé assortie au tissu de base, et mesurer 0.5 cm à 1 cm de largeur, 18 à 20 cm de longueur hors-tout et 9 à10 cm de longueur finie.

Je n'ai jamais entendu le terme de « boucle » pour ce genre d'objet, et mes recherches ne l'ont pas trouvé non plus. Pour moi c'est une question de sémantique.

Une **boucle** est un objet qui se referme sur lui-même, souvent en forme d'anneau, et qui, en couture sert à fermer.

- [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/boucle) :

  > Anneau de forme et de dimension variables, généralement métallique, muni d'un ou de plusieurs ardillons, fixé à l'extrémité d'une courroie ou d'une ceinture pour en assurer et en régler le serrage

Une **bride** est un objet de fixation ou de maintien d'un objet, pas de fermeture.

- [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bride) :

  > Brides d'un bonnet, d'un chapeau, d'une coiffe. Longs rubans cousus de part et d'autre de la coiffure et destinés à être noués sous le menton pour maintenir le chapeau sur la tête.

---

Commentaire de @Eauquidort:

> On dit "lichette" en Belgique, [mot d'étymologie obscure](http://www.lalibre.be/culture/medias-tele/la-lichette-51b894f7e4b0de6db9b056e3).

Effectivement à *lichette* dans le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* on trouve à *lichette*:

> Franç. de Belgique : Petite attache de ruban, cordonnet ou chaînette, servant à suspendre un vêtement, un torchon.

Le mot *attache* employé par ce dictionnaire m'a rappelé que j'ai déjà entendu ce mot utilisé pour ce que j'appelle *une bride de suspension* mais mes recherches dans des magasins en ligne et des dictionnaires ne m'ont conduit qu'à des objets servant à attacher deux parties de vêtement entre elles. Cependant si le mot n'est pas employé par les professionnels de la mercerie, je pense qu'il est couramment employé par les non spécialistes.

Comment: On dit "lichette" en Belgique, mot d'étymologie obscure: http://www.lalibre.be/culture/medias-tele/la-lichette-51b894f7e4b0de6db9b056e3

Comment: @Eauquidort  Je pense qu'il serait utile d'intégrer cette remarque à la réponse, histoire de pérenniser le commentaire, puis-je ?

Comment: @Laure Bien sûr

Comment: Merci, après avoir lu votre réponse je l'ai retrouvé aussi au [GDT](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8354544) avec _cordon/ganse d'accrochage_. Je retiens aussi le belgicisme _lichette_ et les tentatives, vaines dit-on, _accrochette_ et _attachette_, toutes avec ce même suffixe plaisant...